# If either the [noun 1] or the [noun 2]

Tags: conjunction-reduction, either-or

I'm not sure which of the following is correct:

- If either **the** orange or **the** apple falls from the tree...
- If either **the** orange or apple falls from the tree...

I don't know if I need one definite article or two.